# Error 404: Page not found in codeigniter when controller is in subfolder

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Some of the controllers in my CI project are not working. The following is the directory structure:

```
controllers/student/profile/personal.php
```

When I call it using the URL: **localhost/school/student/profile/personal** then it displays 404 error.

**Contents of personal.php file:**

```
class Personal extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        echo "The is Personal Section";
    }
}
```

**Contents of .htaccess file are:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA,PT]
```

I don't know why it is not working. There are other controllers like **controllers/student/login.php** working ok.

**Any Idea?**

Comment: and if you call it `personal` not `Personal` `class personal extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: @CodeBird Still not working?

Comment: Your controller folder does not have a `school` sub-folder but your URL does

Comment: yep there is `school` added in the URL, good eye @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @CodeBird thanks! Also, I am not too familiar with composing `.htaccess` rules so OP might be accounting for this fact in there but I can't recognize anything that would compensate for my observation

Comment: @MonkeyZeus school is the name of the project folder in which I have placed codeigniter files. The other controllers work well with same url scheme. Also the .htaccess and CI index.php file is in school folder, so it does not make sense to add up a school folder within controller directory.

Comment: do you have a file called profile.php in controllers/student/?

Comment: @asim-ishaq my bad, where is this mentioned in your question exactly?

Comment: @asim-ishaq According to the Codeigniter documentation, controller names should be uppercase. Personal not personal. "Note: Class names must start with an uppercase letter." http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: @kevindeleon i changed it to uppercase but still not working.

Comment: @asim-ishaq Could this be a routing problem then? Do you have any custom routes? Are there any controllers in the "profile" folder that do work? I know you reference 'login.php' as working, but it is not in the same folder.

Comment: @kevindeleon login.php is in student folder and it works fine. Profile folder is in student folder as well but no controller within this directory works. I do not have any custom routes defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe CodeIgniter allows organizing controllers into sub-sub folders by default. Sub-folders yes...deeper than that and you run into issues. There are some solutions out there (better or worse) that allow this functionality.  A quick Google search turns this up:

https://degreesofzero.com/article/controllers-in-sub-sub-folders-in-codeigniter.html

Also this:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/190563/

Comment: Creating a MY_Router class resolves this issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter prior to version 3 models and controllers are named in small caps and the class name within the file is named With a Capital first letter
Example if it is class goat the the file should be **goat.php**

Codeigniter 3 models and controllers are named just like how they are called with the files Example if it is class goat the the file should be **Goat.php**

failure to do so in either case depending on your codeigniter version ... will result into a not found error